# Is it possible to use import_export Django lib to export data from more than one table in a same xls doc?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

class OrderResource(resources.ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    model = Order
```

class PaymentOrderAdmin( ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
resource_class = OrderResource

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on how to write questions which get the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but you would have to delve into the source code and override the appropriate methods to read from multiple tables and then combine them into a single dataset for export.

AFAIK there isn't a simple way of doing this but it is on the roadmap.